# BIOS configuration for VMWare Workstation

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I've been trying to find a method to change bios options from within the guest OS. HP provides BiosConfigUtility, Dell provides Client Configuration Utility. Is there any solution from VMWare to change BIOS options of a virtual machine from within the guest OS (like through command prompt or powershell)?

Comment: Isn't this is same as what you are looking for https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.HOWTO95250

Comment: No it is not the same... Through config utilities, you can change the bios options using command prompt or powershell scripts... I don't want to enter the BIOS in the beginning... need to change the options from within the OS

Answer (score 0):

According to the information from vmware there is a solution.

> To make it easier to access the BIOS setup screen, edit the
> configuration (.vmx) of the virtual machine and add or edit one of
> these options:
>
> **bios.forceSetupOnce = "TRUE"**
> This forces entry to the BIOS setup at startup.
>
> **bios.bootDelay = "xxxx"**
> This adds a delay to the initial POST screen, showing it for longer
> and giving you more time to access the BIOS setup, where **xxxx** is the
> number of milliseconds to show the POST screen (There are 1000
> milliseconds in a second.). The maximum value for the boot delay is
> **10000 milliseconds or 10 seconds**.

In my case I had to ***uncheck*** "**Accelerate 3D graphics**" in VM configuration to reach a BIOS prompt, and GRUB prompt, also.